# React Native app rejected for QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES

Tags: react-native, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

So, here's a head scratcher (at least, it is for me).

> Issue found: Less broad app-visibility method should be used.
> We are unable to approve your app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission because >the declared task can be done with a less broad app-visibility method.
>
> One suggested method is to declare your app's need for specific package >visibility using the element. You may refer to the common use cases.

But here's where it gets weird...the permission is not on my merged manifest, or anywhere in my code when searched in VSCode. I've tried every fix going but cannot trace where this permission is being generated or where it is even present!

It has been rejected three times now. Appeals lead to no-where so it must be something in the code.

package.json below.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "name": "MY APP",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.1.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.1.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.1.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.1",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.2.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-game-engine": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-offline": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-promise-rejection-utils": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.7",
    "react-uuid": "^1.0.2",
    "rn-scratch-card": "^1.0.0-beta7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not alone.  I just got this error on my apps as well and have the same situation where it doesn't exist in my codebase.  I'm on 63.3 while I see you are on 69.1 so I know it's not fixed if I attempt to upgrade my dependencies.  Perhaps this is a false finding by Android/Google?

Comment: @chris any of the packages I use match up with your project?

Comment: I did an absolute massive search through all my dependencies for the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES and found that one of mine had it (it's not in your list).  Updating that package removed it.  So for me it was a bad dependency that had the QUERY, I'd suggest you do a full search as well to see.  Also the play store demands you fill in a reason even if you are just replacing with it removed, simply state that "it's being replaced by a version that does not have this requirement".

Comment: @Chris: any updates on your release? I am on 70.1 and got this error without using it. :(

Comment: @Queen I’ve since moved away from this project (and company) but if you do a deep search through your dependencies, you may find which one of your dependencies may be causing it. That or ditch RN 